# WPF Databinding in ControlTemplate not working C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I try to bind a simple bool to a checkbox and a datatrigger in a controltemplate, but nothing is working. The checkbox is only for test purpose. I already went through the posts here, but most problems are caused by setting a property directly and not in the style, thus overwriting it. The datatrigger using the mouseover property is working just fine. Its only the binding to the bool which doesn't work.

My Code so far:
cs:

```
public partial class HostFrame : UserControl
{
    public bool test { get; set; }

    public HostFrame()
    {
        test = true;
        InitializeComponent();          
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="OwnDrawingv2.Elements.HostFrame"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OwnDrawingv2.Elements"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HostFrame}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HostFrame}">
                        <Grid Background="LightBlue" Name="host_grid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="content" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=test}"> <!--Test prupose-->
                            </CheckBox>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="attention" Width="30" Height="30"  Source="/attention_icon.png">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=test}" Value="true">

                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="10" Height="10"  Fill="Black">
                                <Ellipse.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Ellipse.Style>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="10" Height="10"  Fill="Black">
                                <Ellipse.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Ellipse.Style>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

UPDATE: I got an answer for my original question and I understand this. But why are there tutorials in the web, which seem to work without the relativesource?
UPDATE2: I missed one answers information about Datacontext, thank you. The problem is solved.

Comment: First of all, your `test` property is missing a property change notification mechanism. As the property is declared in a UserControl, it should certainly be a dependency property (which notifies about value changes). Second, the DataTrigger Binding is missing a source object. Try `{Binding Path=test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. For the first part: This implementation will follow later ;) You can post this and I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do the following `IsChecked="{Binding Path=test}"` that means your UserControl class is the DataContext of it self (or you didn't say that).
So you have 2 solutions (I guess)

1- Move your Test property to your ViewModel and do your Binding.
2- Use RelativeResource and FindAncestor method (`{Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}`)

PS: IF your HostFrame inherits from Control,UIELement..., It would be better to define a DependencyProperty and do a TemplateBinding

Comment: Thank you for the tip, right now I am looking for some documentation/tutorial to get more information about the topic. Do you have some links?

Comment: [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599954/WPF-TemplateBinding-with-ControlTemplate) is a simple tutorial for TemplateBinding

Answer (score 1):

You have not set a `Datacontext` for your `UserControl` therefore i assume it will be null. You should see the binding error in your output.

On the other hand, your property `test` doesnt't notify changes. You should declare it as a dependency property if it belongs to the UserControl (instead of being part of the ViewModel)

Comment: You should never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl, as this would prevent inheriting the DataContext from the UserControl's parent. Instead, always use `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` Bindings in the UserControl's XAML.

Comment: @Clemens, you are right, but we lacked information about how that UserControl was being used, if it had a parent or not. I didn't mean 'explicitly set a DataContext for it' rather 'be sure it has some kind of DataContext'. I wasn't clear enough.